Why prisma automatically add quotes when type is array
I wanted to store data in array type, but when I try to store an array in Prisma, it automatically put quotes and causes error. I use Next.js
I tried
  const genre = formdata.genre
  const tag = formdata.tag
  console.log('genre', genre)

//another code

const result = await prisma.items.update({
    where: {
      id: id
    },
    data:{
      genre: genre,
      tag: tag
    }
  });

if genre and tag is ['hello', 'world!'],
console says: genre ['hello', 'world!']
But Error says
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.items.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  data: {
    genre: "['hello', 'world!']",
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    tag: "['hello', 'world!']"
  }
}

Argument `genre`: Invalid value provided. Expected itemsUpdategenreInput or String[], provided String.

and this is my schema
model items{
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name String
  genre String[]
  time DateTime
  tag String[]
  try Int
  creater String
}




Prisma expects an array of strings for the genre and tag fields, but you're passing a single string containing the entire array.

convert them into actual string arrays before passing them


const genre = formdata.genre.split(',');
const genre = formdata.tag.split(',');

const result = await prisma.items.update({
  where: {
    id: id
  },
  data:{
    genre: genre,
    tag: tag
  }
});


Wouldn't this add the [ inside the string? the result would be [hello and world!]
